# kafka + Leader none + and kafka broker id not signed in zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have 3 Kafka brokers on Linux RHEL 7.6 (  3 linux machines )

kafka version is 2.7.X

brokers ID's are - `1010,1011,1012`

from kafka described we can see the following

```
 Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 1011,1010,1012        Isr: 1010
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 1012    Replicas: 1012,1011,1010        Isr: 1012,1011
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 1011    Replicas: 1010,1012,1011        Isr: 1011,1012
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: none    Replicas: 1011,1012,1010        Isr: 1010
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 1011    Replicas: 1012,1010,1011        Isr: 1011
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 5    Leader: none    Replicas: 1010,1011,1012        Isr: 1010
```

from Zookeeper cli we can see that broker `id 1010` not defined

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 10] ls /brokers/ids
[1011, 1012]
```

and from the log -  `state-change.log`

we can see the following

```
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-6 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-9 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-8 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-11 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-10 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-46 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-45 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-48 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-47 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
[2021-12-16 14:15:36,170] WARN [Broker id=1010] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1010 with correlation id 485 epoch 323 for partition __consumer_offsets-49 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
```

by ls -ltr , we can see that `controller.log` and `state-change.log` are not update from `Dec 16`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root kafka 343477146 Dec 16 14:15 controller.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root kafka 207911766 Dec 16 14:15 state-change.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka  68759461 Dec 16 14:15 kafkaServer-gc.log.6.current
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root kafka   6570543 Dec 17 09:42 log-cleaner.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288242 Dec 20 00:39 server.log.10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524289332 Dec 20 01:37 server.log.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288452 Dec 20 02:35 server.log.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288625 Dec 20 03:33 server.log.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288395 Dec 20 04:30 server.log.6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288237 Dec 20 05:27 server.log.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524289136 Dec 20 06:25 server.log.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288142 Dec 20 07:25 server.log.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288187 Dec 20 08:21 server.log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 524288094 Dec 20 10:52 server.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka    323361 Dec 20 19:50 kafkaServer-gc.log.0.current
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 323132219 Dec 20 19:50 server.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root kafka  15669106 Dec 20 19:50 kafkaServer.out
```

what we did until now is that:

we restart all 3 zookeeper servers
we restart all kafka brokers

but still kafka broker `1010`  appears as `leader none`  , and not in zookeeper data

**additional info**

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 11] get /controller
{"version":1,"brokerid":1011,"timestamp":"1640003679634"}
cZxid = 0x4900000b0c
ctime = Mon Dec 20 12:34:39 UTC 2021
mZxid = 0x4900000b0c
mtime = Mon Dec 20 12:34:39 UTC 2021
pZxid = 0x4900000b0c
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x27dd7cf43350080
dataLength = 57
numChildren = 0
```

**from kafka01**

```
more meta.properties
#
#Tue Nov 16 07:45:36 UTC 2021
cluster.id=D3KpekCETmaNveBJzE6PZg
version=0
broker.id=1010
```

**relevant ideas**

in topics disk we have the following files ( additionally to topics partitions )

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka    91 Nov 16 07:45 meta.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka   161 Dec 15 16:04 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka 13010 Dec 15 16:20 replication-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka  1928 Dec 17 09:42 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kafka    80 Dec 17 09:42 log-start-offset-checkpoint
```

any idea if deletion of one or more of above files can help with our issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you've shown is that broker 1010 isn't healthy and you probably have unclear leader election disabled.

`ls /brokers/ids` shows you the running, healthy brokers from Zookeeper's point of view.

Meanwhile, the data in the `/topics` znodes refers to a broker listed in the replica set that is not running, or at least not reporting back to Zookeeper, which you'd see in `server.log`

If you have another broker, you can use the partition reassignment tool to manually remove/change broker 1010 data from each partition of all topics it hosts, which would remove old replica information in Zookeeper, and should force a new leader

You shouldn't delete checkpoint files, but you can delete old, rotated log files after you've determined they're not needed anymore

Comment: not so understand how to change broker 1010 in order to force new leader ?

Comment: is it possible to delete all topics include all content from broker 1010 and then restart kafka service so by this I will create new broker id?

Comment: Since you cannot reduce replication factors, you'd need to first have a forth, healthy broker. Then you can use the reassignment tool (Cloudera documentation, but still applies to all Kafkas) https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.1/kafka-managing/topics/kafka-manage-cli-reassign-overview.html

Comment: `broker.id` is set in your properties file, not by topic data

Comment: so in that case why not jut change the broker id and then restart kafka service ?

Comment: we cant add new kafka machine as 4 machine - because this is physical machine , and its costs a lot

Comment: You can, but `/topics` data in Zookeeper will still list 1010 and so you still would need to manually change all topics that you'd deleted there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240295/discussion-between-jessica-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: so if I can change the broker id as you said , then I maybe can also to delete all topics in kafka01 , so all other replica topics will copied from other kafka - what you said about this ?

Comment: Sure, but you should really figure out why the broker itself is not healthy rather than start to format it and run into the same issue again in the future.

Comment: actually we want to fix the kafka ( for now root cause no so important ) , back to our suggestion to change the broker id and remove all topics , is the deletion include to remove all other files as - cleaner-offset-checkpoint , replication-offset-checkpoint , etc??

Comment: Sure. `grep 'log.dirs' server.properties`, and remove everything in those folders

Comment: I assume that we need also to delete the - meta.properties , since broker id defined in server.properties

Comment: `meta.properties` stores a clusterId, not a broker id

Comment: I think all this problem was because the errors that we get before week about Too many open files , since then we have this mass ( last days we increase the number of open files ) but after kafka service restart its no so help